# How can I add an azure function to an API Management using ARM template

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm using this ARM template to add an external Azure function (already defined in other template) to my API management but I get a validation error (resource is not defined in template). Is there any solution to automate mapping azure function with an API management?

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {...},
"resources": [

    {
        "apiVersion": "2017-03-01",
        "name": "[parameters('apiManagementServiceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": {},
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
            "capacity": "[parameters('skuCount')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "publisherEmail": "[parameters('publisherEmail')]",
            "publisherName": "[parameters('publisherName')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('apiManagementServiceName'), '/', parameters('indexerApp'))]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', parameters('apiManagementServiceName'))]",
            "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('indexerApp'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "displayName": "[parameters('indexerApp')]",
            "apiRevision": "1",
            "description": "Import from \"[parameters('indexerApp')]\" Function App",
            "path": "[parameters('indexerApp')]",
            "protocols": [
                "https"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource that links directly to a Logic App, Function or other internal Azure resource is a [**backends**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/backends) (note plural):

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends",
  "apiVersion": "2019-01-01",
  "properties": {
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "resourceId": "string",
    "properties": {
      "serviceFabricCluster": {
        "clientCertificatethumbprint": "string",
        "maxPartitionResolutionRetries": "integer",
        "managementEndpoints": [
          "string"
        ],
        "serverCertificateThumbprints": [
          "string"
        ],
        "serverX509Names": [
          {
            "name": "string",
            "issuerCertificateThumbprint": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "credentials": {
      "certificate": [
        "string"
      ],
      "query": {},
      "header": {},
      "authorization": {
        "scheme": "string",
        "parameter": "string"
      }
    },
    "proxy": {
      "url": "string",
      "username": "string",
      "password": "string"
    },
    "tls": {
      "validateCertificateChain": "boolean",
      "validateCertificateName": "boolean"
    },
    "url": "string",
    "protocol": "string"
  }
}
```

I *believe* that if you specify the `resourceId` property, the Azure infrastructure automatically wires up the other properties to your Function (or Logic App). The format of the "id" is not obvious, it expects a **Management URI**, the format of which is [mentioned in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#return-value)

You then link this created backends to an operation using the operation's policy - this is a pain to express in ARM templates, but it should contain a policy expression:

```
<set-backend-service backend-id=\"[name of your backend]\"/>
```

An example of how these are linked together can be found at [this linked sample](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric-scripts-and-templates/blob/master/templates/service-integration/apim.json). It features Service Fabric but it should be generally applicable to Functions as well.